# Django 1.7 workaround to use drf-spectacular

Tags: python, django, drf-spectacular

I am trying to use drf-spectacular for annotating my existing python api, but i am currently using django-1.7 in my application, and this tool has a dependency of django-2.2 what can be done as quick solution or any suggetion??

Comment: Django 1.7 came out a decade ago, and has long been out of support. It has many unpatched security issues and won’t be compatible with most Django packages. It is long past time to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.7 came out a decade ago, and has long been out of support. It has many unpatched security issues and won’t be compatible with most Django packages. It is long past time to upgrade. I’d recommend upgrading in steps, to Django 1.8, 1.9, 1.10, 1.11, 2.0, 2.2, 3.2, then 4.2 to be on the current Long term support (LTS) release.

It is past time to pay off your technical debt, and shouldn’t take too long. Upgrades skills are also essential for any Django project to have long term viability. Good luck!